# Comparing feature contribution in supervised classification

Tags: classification, anova, feature-selection, scikit-learn

I’m doing supervised classification (SVM and KNN) with Scikit learn and I would like to compare how well each of my 30 features contribute to make the classification succeed.

I use the `SelectKBest` class to get the respective scores of all my features (although I don’t want to reduce the number of features as SelectKBest is intended to be used for). Here is how I get the feature scores :

```
selectkbest=SelectKBest(score_func=f_classif,k="all") 
selectkbest.fit(X,y)
scores=selectkbest.scores_
```

I don't understand how these scores are computed. The scikit documentation only says that the function f_classif returns ANOVA f-values but I was not able to understand what it corresponds to.

Is there other ways I could compare the efficiency of my features ?